# Why only 2GB for 32 bit computer?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Upon installing mongodb in my laptop the tutorial told 32-bit versions of MongoDB only support databases smaller than 2GB. What is the reason behind it.And the link is here              [32 Bit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 32-bit MongoDB processes are limited to about 2 gb of data.  This has
>   come as a surprise to a lot of people who are used to not having to
>   worry about that.  The reason for this is that the MongoDB storage
>   engine uses memory-mapped files for performance.
>
> By not supporting more than 2gb on 32-bit, we’ve been able to keep our
>   code much simpler and cleaner.  This greatly reduces the number of
>   bugs, and reduces the time that we need to release a 1.0 product. The
>   world is moving toward all 64-bit very quickly.  Right now there
>   aren’t too many people for whom 64-bit is a problem, and in the long
>   term, we think this will be a non-issue.

Source: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations

Comment: yeah thanks mate... got the doubt cleared/

Comment: I don't mean to pick at this but I do find it odd how someone can get 4 upvotes for copying and pasting...